# Problem with &star; html entity in android

Tags: html, html-entities

I'm using the ☆ ( `& s t a r ;`) html entity on a webpage ( http://www.shermanbrothers.com ), but it's not being decoded correctly in the android browser.  It actually lierally outputs: `& s t a r ;`  I was thinking and hoping that html entities had good support in the browsers, but not in this case, at least.

I read somewhere that using the numbered equivalents has better support but I haven't been able to find a resource for translating entities.

My server is serving unicode, so maybe that is a better alternative?

Comment: Try `&#9734;`. from http://htmlentities.net/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good site for this is the Unicode Search site, found [here](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/search.htm). What you want is probably ☆

Decimal: `&#9734;` 
Hexadecimal: `&#x2606;`

Answer (score 2):

The one you want is `&#9733;` (black star) or the `&#9734;` (white star with black borders). This should work in all browsers, including the android/ios one.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason that you aren't using an image instead?  In that case, you avoid any differences that may exist in browser decoding.